# pyqt mouse held down eventfilter

Tags: pyqt, qevent

I am new to PyQt and I can't figure this out. I am trying to install an eventFilter so that when a QPushButton is pressed and held down, the system increments a value at a certain rate (This will probably be a QTimer). I have a second QPushButton on the same page that when it is pressed and held, should decrememt the value. The system needs to differentiate between a  single click and a press and hold.Here's what I have so far, which is not bad but I am confident there's a more efficient way of doing this.

```
class App(QtGui.QMainWindow, App_Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(App, self).__init__(parent)
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        App_Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        #Set Up mouse and install event filter.
        self.mouse_state = app.mouseButtons()
        self.mouse_state == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton
        self.increment_Button.installEventFilter(self)
        self.decrement_Button.installEventFilter(self)
        self.hoveringover = 'Null'

        #Timer for when mouse is held down.
        self.mouseheld = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.mouseheld.timeout.connect(self.update)
        self.mouseheld.start(500) #trigger every second.
        self.mouseheld.timeout.connect(self.mouse_held_event)

    #To figure out which/if we are hovering over a button.
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Enter:
           self.hoveringover = obj.objectName()
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Leave:
           self.hoveringover = 'Null'
        return super(App, self).eventFilter(obj, event)

    def mouse_held_event(self):
        #Set up mouse.
        self.is_mouse_held = 1
        self.mouse_state = app.mouseButtons()
        self.mouse_state == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton
        if int(self.mouse_state) == 1:
            if self.hoveringover == 'increment_Button':
               self.increment()
            elif self.hoveringover == 'decrement_Button':
               self.decrement()
```